# How to start two applications simultaneously in Task Scheduler without one waiting for other being closed?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I want to delay the startup of two apps by a minute. So I created a task that's triggered at log on.

[Startup Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsVbE.jpg) (I'm not allowed to embed an image)

However, only the first app gets started. The second doesn't start unless I quit the first app.
Is there a way to start both simultaneously, without one waiting for the other getting closed?

**EDIT:**

I'm currently using a batch script that runs these two applications. And I've made the task run this script.

**About my rejection of the suggested edit:** I'll embed this image when the *"rules"* allow me to. I don't want any other person doing it for me.

Comment: create two tasks, or start them via script which is started from task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Within Task Scheduler, create two separate tasks, with the same trigger and other information.

Comment: That was my first thought, too. But I thought if there were a way to do it without creating two separate tasks.

Comment: as far as I am aware, I don't believe there is a simple method, you could call something else which calls the 2 programs you want to run. This may be over complicated for what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I upvoted your answer, but it doesn't show up because of the _rules_.